# Prove that Bellman Ford maximises objective function

Tags: linear-programming, proof, maximize, bellman-ford

Prove that Bellman-Ford when applied to the constraint graph of a linear programming problem with constraints of the form Xj - Xi <= Wij maximizes the function X1 + ... + Xn subject to constraints Xj - Xi <= Wij and Xi <=0.
I am completely stuck in here. Please give some hints to guide me through the solution.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a homework help site. It's a Q&A site. Tell us what you've tried so far, and ask a specific question that will allow you to move forward if answered.

Comment: Up to now I know that Xi <= 0 means that we have a node with key 0 on the graph that has 0 weight edges towards all other nodes in the graph. Also it is clear that the max value of the function cannot be > than 0 since all Xi <= 0. At this point I just can't proceed further. I need some idea on how to use this knowledge.

Comment: Hint: prove that for every feasible solution (i.e.., a set of Xi values that satisfy all constraints) to this LP there is a set of valid distances in the constraint graph (i.e., for every node the node is no further than the distance assigned to it). Try to create the valid distances from the Xi values, it's really easy. Then prove the converse: if you have a set of valid distances, from that create a feasible solution to the LP.